# Akgregator probelms: try icon and favicons

Tags: unity, icons, kde

I use [Akgregator](http://userbase.kde.org/Akregator/) in Unity and I have two problems:

- I don't see the try icon (with the number of new messages):

  [image]
- I don't see the favicons of the feeds, but only the default icon:

  [image]

How to solve these problems?